# How to display color image from camera to a picturebox by applying color pallette

Tags: c#, .net, c#-4.0

Im using a hikvision color camera to grab images. I have been working with monochrome camera and the exisiting code that I have works well for 8bpp indexed pixel format. The camera has RGB8 pixel format.

My code to display images from monochrome camera is ;

```
        using (Bitmap bmp1 = new Bitmap(stFrameInfo.stFrameInfo.nWidth, stFrameInfo.stFrameInfo.nHeight, stFrameInfo.stFrameInfo.nWidth, PixelFormat.Format8bppIndexed, stFrameInfo.pBufAddr))
                {
                    ColorPalette cp = bmp1.Palette;
                for (int i = 0; i < 256; ++i)
                {
                    cp.Entries[i] = Color.FromArgb(i, i, i);
                }
                bmp1.Palette = cp;
                this.Invoke((MethodInvoker)delegate
                {
                    imageBox1.Image = bmp1;
                    
                });
```

But this shows a grayscale image full of lines with the color camera. How do I correct this to get proper color image?

Answer (score 0):

Your palette is not created correctly. `Color.FromArgb(i, i, i)` will just set each palette color to a grayscale color, and that is probably not what you want.

[RGB8](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/8-bit_color) uses bits in the order:

```
Bit    7  6  5  4  3  2  1  0
Data   R  R  R  G  G  G  B  B
```

So to get the color value for each palette index you need to do some bit manipulation.

```
var r = (int)(byte.MaxValue * 8f / ((i >> 5) & 0b0000111))
var g = (int)(byte.MaxValue * 8f / ((i >> 2) & 0b0000111))
var b = (int)(byte.MaxValue * 4f / ((i >> 0) & 0b0000011))
```

I *think* that is correct, but I have not tested it, so I may have made some mistakes.

I would note that you use the width for both the width and the stride. This  *might* be correct, but it is possible for the width and stride to differ, so it is common to have separate parameters for these. Might be worth doublechecking.

Comment: It threw an array out of bound exception. I just read the sdk docs and they have a method to copy image to imagebox handle like:  stDisplayInfo.hWnd = imageBox1.Handle  Its working well, but as soon as I zoom out or try to copy the image it goes blank. Is there any way to copy the image into bitmap?

Comment: @Starscream that is not copying a image, just a handle. And it sounds like some proprietary library that may or may not have helper methods to convert the bitmap to a regular rgb24/32 image. You can copy images by creating a graphics object with Graphics.FromImage and draw the image, but I'm not sure that would help you to much. If you have errors it is important to at least figure out the reasons for the errors so you can figure out if you can solve it or need to do something else.